# gulp + mocha + typescript unit test

Tags: node.js, typescript, gulp, mocha.js

I have an error when I create new instance on test file.
This is my test:

```
    /// <reference path="../typings/globals/mocha/index.d.ts" />

import Person from '../src/person/person';

describe('Person', () => {

    let person: Person;

    beforeEach(() => {
        person = new Person();

    });

    describe('getName', () => {

        it('return name', () => {

        });
    });
});
```

And my gulp task:

```
var gulp = require("gulp");
var ts = require("gulp-typescript");
var mocha = require("gulp-mocha");
var tsProject = ts.createProject("./tsconfig.json");

gulp.task('watch', function () {
    gulp.watch('./src/**/**/*.ts', ['ts']);
});

gulp.task('ts', function () {
    return tsProject.src()
        .pipe(tsProject())
        .js.pipe(gulp.dest("dist"));
});

gulp.task('test', function () {

    return gulp.src('./tests/*.spec.ts',
        {
            base: '.'
        })
        /*transpile*/
        .pipe(tsProject())
        /*flush to disk*/
        .pipe(gulp.dest('.'))
        /*execute tests*/
        .pipe(mocha())
        .on("error", function(err) {
            console.log(err)
        });
});

gulp.task("default", ['watch', 'ts']);
```

So, when I launch the test an error occured, but if I comment **person = new Person()** then everything works.

Somebody knows what I am doing wrong?

EDIT:
Sorry, this is the error:

```
module.js:472
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '../src/person/person'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:470:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:418:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/emesislol/projects/persons/tests/person.test.js:4:21)
    at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at /Users/emesislol/projects/persons/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:222:27
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Mocha.loadFiles (/Users/emesislol/projects/persons/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:219:14)
    at Mocha.run (/Users/emesislol/projects/persons/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:487:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/emesislol/projects/persons/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha:459:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:605:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:420:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:139:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:535:3
```

Comment: You have to specify exactly the error that occurs in detail, otherwise the question does not follow the rules.  It is very frustrating that you did not paste the error and just said 'an error occurred'.

Comment: Where exactly is your `person` file? Looks to me like it should be `./src/person/person.ts` or `./src/person/person/index.ts`. Since typescript can't find the module, my guess is that that isn't the correct path.

Comment: I found the problem! I was pointing to the .ts file but I should have pointed to the compiled .js. Now it works! thanks guys!